# Php Unexpected T_FOR, expecting ). Creating multi-dimensional arrays using for()

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

here is my code. What I am trying to achieve is get text like this

```
Hola   Hi
Pollo   Chicken
Queso   Cheese
```

and so on, and be able to make an array out of it such that

array[0][1] is Hi.
here is my code, the error is on line 13

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$message = $_POST['text'];
$words2 = explode("\r\n", $message);
$words = explode("\t", $words2[0]);
$numberoflines = count($words2);
echo $numberoflines;
for($i=0; $i<$numberoflines; $i++){
$words[$i] = $line;
$arrayline = explode("\t", $line);
$cow = array( 
    for($u=0; $u<2; $u++){
        array($arrayline[$u])
            }
        );
}
}
?>
<html>
<form method = "POST" method ="changetext.php">
<textarea name="text">
</textarea>
<input type="submit" value = "Flip!" name="submit">
</form>

</html>
```

Comment: since when can you use a for loop inside of an array() ?!?

Comment: Since never. And that's why you're getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe thats what you wanted to achieve ?!?

```
for($i=0; $i<$numberoflines; $i++){
 $arraycols= explode("\t", $words[$i]);
 foreach($arraycols as $col){
    $list[$i][] = $col;
 }
}
```

so Array $list is $list[row][col]

if i got right what is inside the $words Array. Your code is a little messi ;)

Comment: No... not really. The array right now has just the lines for example
Hola    hi
I want to break this array up into a multidimensional array such that the first array determines the line, and the second one which word in the line.

Comment: Ok so you want to have a 2 dimensional array listing 

$array[line][word]

i chage my code

Comment: somehow when being stored as a 2-d array, it stores everything in the first number for some weird reason.

Comment: check if numberoflines is correc,t otherweise i will always be 0 or something ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$words = array();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    // Break down the text as lines:
    $lines = explode("\r\n", $_POST['text']);

    // For every line...
    foreach($lines as $line){
        // Seperate the 2 words (seperated by a tab)
        $words[] = explode("\t", $line);
    }

    // Print the result:
    var_dump($words);
}
```

Comment: Ok, but then how would I print it? All I get is Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Flip! ) )

Comment: I'm sorry, I assumed the variable name was 'submit', while it was 'text'. Try it again with the edited code above.

Comment: great! thanks a ton. and I assume this makes it a 2 d array because the explode makes it an array.

Comment: Well, it's an array inside an array, so is't not 2d. You can make it 2d though, is that what you want? So if you call `$words['myword'];` returns `somethingspanish`?

Comment: no, i get it. its like a pseudo 2d array, right? its not actually 2d, but functionally its the same? at least in this scenario.

Comment: Yes, Right now, you have an array, containing all the rows as arrays. Those arrays have 2 values, the first and the last word. In JSON: [{first, last}, {fists, last}]. You can see the result by replacing the `print_r($words);` with `var_dump($words);`